# How do I change DNS settings for 3G?

Tags: samsung, 3g, mobile-network, mobile-data, dns

So I can use Twitter. It is okay when I use WiFi. But in 3G I cannot change DNS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Jelly Bean (MR2) or KitKat, you can use my app: [Override DNS for KitKat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mx17.overridedns).
For lower versions of Android there are tons of free apps which do the same.